# How to get shader storage block's variable offset when using layout(packed) or layout(shared) in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader-storage-buffer

If I have a shader storage block defined in GLSL like this:

```
buffer test_block
{
    type1 var1;
    type2 var2;
    type3 var3;
};
```

How to get the offset of one of the variable in this block?

We know that if it is a uniform block just like this:

```
uniform test_block
{
    type1 var1;
    type2 var2;
    type3 var3;
};
```

we can get offset in this way, for example get the offset of `var2`:

```
char[] var2_name = "var2";
int var2_index;
glGetUniformIndices(program_id, 1, &var2_name, &var2_index);

int var2_offset;
glGetActiveUniformsiv(program_id, 1, &var2_index, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, &var2_offset);

// then var2_offset is what you want
```

This is for uniform block. But I can't find any tutorial of getting offset of shader storeage block variable's offset.

(Don't tell me to use std140 or std430, I know this way. I want to write program don't depend on specific memory layout. Just get the offset programmatically.)

I tried to find functions jusk like `glGetUniformIndices` and `glGetActiveUniformsiv` which is suite for shader storage block. But there is no such functions.

I expect one way to get shader storage block variable's offset programmatically just like getting uniform block variable's offset.

Comment: "*I want to write program don't depend on specific memory layout. Just get the offset programmatically.*" You really shouldn't. You depend on the writer of the shader to provide a specific name within the SSBO. You depend on them to give this variable a certain type. So why not just force them to put those named types in a certain order? Your code is going to be depended on what is in the SSBO anyway. Why is requiring the user to follow a layout that much more of a burden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [program interface query](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_query) API is a generic tool for querying any of the external interface components of a program. Inputs, outputs, uniforms, and yes, storage buffers. There are separate APIs for many of these interfaces (like `glGetUniformIndices`), but a generic one was created that accounts for all of the existing ones.

As well as SSBOs.

The different kinds of queryable properties are called "interfaces". Properties about uniform blocks are queried through the `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK` interface, but the *members* of a uniform block are queried through the `GL_UNIFORM` interface. Similarly, the `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK` is for querying properties of a storage block, but properties of the actual members of the block are queried through the `GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE` interface.

So the program interface query equivalent of your uniform querying code would be:

```
GLuint var2_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(program_id, GL_UNIFORM, "var2");

GLenum props[] = {GL_OFFSET};
GLint var2_offset;

glGetProgramResourceiv(program_id, GL_UNIFORM, var2_index, 1, props, 1, nullptr, &var2_offset);
```

The SSBO equivalent would be:

```
GLuint var2_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(program_id, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, "var2");

GLenum props[] = {GL_OFFSET};
GLint var2_offset;

glGetProgramResourceiv(program_id, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, var2_index, 1, props, 1, nullptr, &var2_offset);
```